# My network seems to work perfectly but I get an error when I restart it

Tags: 16.10

(Ubuntu server 16.10 64bit) Installed on Dell PowerEdge R610

```
networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code
```

Hi, This is an error message I get when I restart the network service like so:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

And it tells me to run `systemctl status networking.service`

This gives me:

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-12-05 15:24:10 EST; 34s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 5638 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 ifup[5638]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 ifup[5638]: Failed to bring up eno1.
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 05 15:24:10 mip-zm01 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It says "Failed to bring up eno1." but eno1 is my main interface and it is working perfectly well...I think...

Is there something I should worry about?

The content of my interfaces file:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo eno1 eno2
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.1.85
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.85
dns-nameservers 172.30.99.1

iface eno1 inet6 auto
iface eno2 inet static
address 172.30.99.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
dns-nameservers 172.30.99.1

iface eno2 inet6 auto
```

Comment: can you post your eno1 config from /etc/network/interfaces please? Do you have multiple interfaces connected to the network?

Comment: I have 4 interfaces but I only use 2. They are both connected. And each on separate switch.

Comment: Your address, and gateway are the same. Did you mean for that?

Comment: Yes it is intentional